# Cordova Native Audio - Multi audio at same time

Tags: android, ios, cordova, audio, ionic-framework

How can we play at exactly the same time multi sounds selected with checkboxes?

For example, let's say, we have 5 checkboxes and we select 3 of them to play at the same time.

I am trying to use the Cordova Native Audio plugging to implement this.

Right now, following the docs, I have this:

```
// Preload audio resources
window.plugins.NativeAudio.preloadComplex( 'pewpewpew', 'assets/pewpewpew.mp3', 1, 1, 0, function(msg){
}, function(msg){
    console.log( 'error: ' + msg );
});


window.plugins.NativeAudio.preloadComplex( 'soldier', 'assets/soldier.mp3', 1, 1, 0, function(msg){
}, function(msg){
    console.log( 'error: ' + msg );
});


window.plugins.NativeAudio.preloadComplex( 'effects', 'assets/effects.mp3', 1, 1, 0, function(msg){
}, function(msg){
    console.log( 'error: ' + msg );
});
    
// Play
window.plugins.NativeAudio.play( 'pewpewpew' );
window.plugins.NativeAudio.loop( 'soldier' );
window.plugins.NativeAudio.loop( 'effects' );
```

and this checkboxes [example](http://play.ionic.io/app/89d16b54285b).

How can I implement the checkbox with the sound, and start the selected sounds at the same time?